# "is very low quality" vs "has very low quality"

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct?

This question is very low quality?

or

This question has very low quality?

or

This question has a very low quality?

Answer (score 6):

Normally... you would say the third, but I've always said:

> This question **is of** very low quality.

This is most common. However, you can parse it in other ways:

In **informal** situations, you can omit the 'of' to get:

> This question is low quality.

**Though this is considered slang by some, and I'd avoid it where possible.**

You can say:

> This question has a low quality.

Where the 'quality' is an abstract noun applied to the question. You can reword the statement to have:

> The quality of this question is low.

...And this is also quite common.

*If I may, I don't consider the question to be of bad quality at all.*

Answer (score 5):

We'll see the sentences you asked:

> This question is very low quality - the question **itself** is a low-quality question. In other words - it's *a low-quality* question. 
>  
>    This question has very low quality - *has* suggests possession. The 'quality' here is the property of the question. Something like This question has a detailed view of the asker. 
>  
>   This question has **a** very low quality -it's the same as the second one but here, you are making 'quality' a countable noun. Quality is [both uncountable and countable noun.](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/quality?q=quality)

However, what looks natural to me is -"This question is **of** very low quality." OR "This is a very low-quality question."

Comment: So you mean all of them are correct somehow?

Comment: @mok yes, one or the other way, they convey the message. But prefer the last one which I said in my answer. It creates no ambiguity.

Comment: MMJZ says he prefers "This question is of very low quality." , do you agree?

Comment: @mok yes yes, I said that there in my last sentence. That's fine.